# Yes/No: Is $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

We know that $\mathbb{Q} [x,y]/(x)$ is  isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[y]$.

My question is  that

> Is $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is field  ?  Yes/No

**My attempt:** I think  yes, because  we know  $ \mathbb{Q}[x] $ is a field and an integral domain  in a similar way  we can also said that $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is a field and an integral domain

Is its true ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a field: $x$ has no multiplicative inverse.

Comment: oksss @Ihf  i mean  $\mathbb{Q}$ is field  i thinks  im not getting the concept

Comment: Since you know that $\mathbb{Q} [x,y]/(x)$, can you show that $(x)$ is not maximal? Can you think about any larger ideal?

Comment: You may confuse $\mathbb Q[x]$ with $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is an algebraic number....

Comment: exactly im confused  with  $\mathbb{Q} [\alpha ]$@N.S.  i think $ (x,y) $ will be  the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$